# Handling exceptions in C++/CLI

Tags: exception, visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

In unmanaged C++ the current thinking is to always catch exceptions via const reference.

I'm not that experienced with managed C++ (although I'm getting to grips with the differences) but I'm wondering, what is the best way to catch exceptions here? Would exceptions ever be caught by handle i.e.

```
try
{
}
catch( ExceptionType^ ex )
{
}
```

.. and if so, would there be any caveats?

Comment: Quote: `Biggest mistake is assuming that it is similar to C++`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For handling managed code exceptions, yes that's the way to do it.

However if you are using Managed C++, I imagine this is becase you have the need to interop with native code (or else you are just a masochist? sorry, I am no fan of Managed C++), in which case things are more complicated.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/liviuc/archive/2009/10/13/.net-interop-and-exception-handling-in-mixed-applications.aspx) for some background on mixed-mode exception handling issues.

Comment: Unlike you, I *do* appreciate C++/CLI (it is its official name) but I wouldn't use it outside of an interop scenario either. You really seldom catch .NET exceptions in the C++/CLI world. However, you should catch every C++ exception and rethrow them in a .NET form. Since you throw a handle in this situation, it is logical that you catch a handle when you must catch .NET exceptions.

Comment: My main objection is the pretence that it's so simple to interoperate with real (ie. native) C++. For interop it's sometimes a must, I am sure. No interop?  Just use C#.

Comment: I can't agree more. But I can't help but say that it's much more pleasant to use C++/CLI and .NET than ATL and COM. The sad fact is that nothing is simple under windows.

Answer (score 4):

When you throw a managed exception, then there is no way to catch it except by garbage-collected handle. Managed code has much stricter rules about what can and cannot be thrown, unlike C++.